# Can't get the tabs value (name) in VBA macro

Tags: vba, excel

I'm stuck here. below is my vba macro. I want to lookup againts other tabs but the result only give me 
`=VLOOKUP(BE2, $BQ$2:$BQ$6, 1, 0)`
 but not the tabs name.. Why? How can I get the sheets name?

```
Set myValues = Application.InputBox("Please select a:", Type:=8)
Set myResults = Application.InputBox("Please select a next sheet:", Type:=8)

On Error Resume Next
Set myValues = myValues.Offset
FirstRow = myValues.Row
FinalRow = Cells(65536, myResults.Column).End(xlUp).Row

Range("BF2").Formula = _
"=VLOOKUP(" & Cells(FirstRow, myValues.Column).Address(False, False) & ", " & _
"  " & myResults.Address & " , 1, 0)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. You just need to set the *Address External* argument to *True*.
Something like:

```
myResults.Address(External:=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.Address` property only returns the row and column reference unless you set the `External` parameter to `True`.  See below:

```
Range("BF2").Formula = _
"=VLOOKUP(" & Cells(FirstRow, myValues.Column).Address(False, False) & ", " & _
"  " & myResults.Address(External:=True) & " , 1, 0)"
```

If you don't want the workbook name in the reference, you can build the reference using the `.Worksheet.Name` property of the `Range` object.  See below:

```
Range("BF2").Formula = _
"=VLOOKUP(" & Cells(FirstRow, myValues.Column).Address(False, False) & ", " & _
"  " & myResults.Worksheet.Name & "!" & myResults.Address & " , 1, 0)"
```

See the [Range.Address Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff837625(v=office.14).aspx) on MSDN for more information.